# torch custom standard deviation without nan or 0

Tags: r, pytorch, tensor, torch

I got a 3 dimension torch tensor like :

```
torch_tensor
(1,.,.) = 
  25   9 nan  16
   5  18 nan  12

(2,.,.) = 
   5  18 nan  12
   1  36   4   9
[ CPUFloatType{2,2,4} ]
```

and i want to reduce the third dimension with standard deviation std().
but as you know with torch you cant remove nan in std().

is there a way to implement custom std_ignoring_nan() function? (or ignoring 0 if i replace nan by 0)

the result i need is not obviously a pure standard deviation

any suggestion?

P.S. : i'm running it on R and it seems that's no nan_mean function in torch with R :(

Comment: The stats function `sd` will ignore `NA`s with `na.rm=TRUE`.  If that doesn't meet your needs, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi! Yes the base R sd function can na.rm. Dont think that base function works in this case beaucause the torch function reduce dimension. I’ll try il that’s works with base!